# postgresql how to create a exclude constraint on integer array to prevent array value overlap?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

When I add an exclude constraint on a table to prevent two rows with same value in int[], I got this error message:

> data type integer[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ref_id INT REFERENCES x,
  purchase_ids INT[],
  EXCLUDE USING GIST(purchase_ids WITH &&) WHERE(ref_id IS NULL)
);
```

Comment: I looked everywhere and it seems like not many people have attempted this before. PostgreSQL's manual page for [CREATE OPERATOR CLASS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createopclass.html) has, at the end, an example for what it seems is exactly what you need (a GIST operator class for int[]), however it fails on my server. Perhaps you'll have better luck!

Comment: thanks Ziggy, I have a bad luck also

Comment: You can of course very simply solve this by using a table with a `PRIMARY KEY` for the `purchase_ids` instead of an `int[]`. Do you really need to store the data in an array?

Comment: @Patrick It's great if store data in an array. My colleague had figure it out by adding a intarray extension which supports overlap operation in exclude constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My colleague figured it out by create an extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS intarray;
```

After created this extension, I can add exclude constraint for preventing two rows with same element in array.